# How to use CollectionViewSource to filter ObservableCollection<T> displayed in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen lots of similar questions but I've not been able to find either a question/answer or tutorial which clearly lists out all of the components required to get this to work. I'm trying to follow MVVM but as this is entirely a UI concern I'm not against doing some code-behind.

What I am trying to achieve:

- `ListView.ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`
- Filter the displayed items in `ListView` based on a `TextBox`
- Filter is updated as user types in `TextBox`

In my `ViewModel` I have something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
{
    get { return _customers; }
    set
    {
        _customers= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Customers");
    }
}

private Customer _selected_Customer;
public Customer Selected_Customer
{
    get { return _selected_Customer; }
    set
    {
        _selected_Customer= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Selected_Customer");
    }
}

private string _filtered_Name;
public string Filtered_Name
{
    get { return _filtered_Name; }
    set
    {
        _filtered_Name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Filtered_Name");
    }
}
```

And in my XAML it's like this:

```xml
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs"
                      x:Name="Customer_Details_View"
                      Source="{Binding Path=Customers}"/>

<TextBox x:Name="Filtered_Name" Text="{Binding Filtered_Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Customer_Details_View}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_Customer, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I want to filter my `ObservableCollection<Customer>` with the following logic: `Customer.Name.ToLower().Contains(Filtered_Name.ToLower())`

How to I bind the `TextBox.Text` to the `CollectionViewSource` or utilize the `CollectionViewSource.Filter` event to apply the above filter?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to declare the collectionviewsource in your VM and bind directly to it.  Once you've done that you can change the filter as answered in this question [CollectionViewSource, how to filter data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497506/collectionviewsource-how-to-filter-data)

VM Example, may not work without massaging.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CollectionViewSourceExample
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _filter;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            SourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            SourceCollection.Add("Fred Flintstone");
            SourceCollection.Add("Wilma Flintstone");
            SourceCollection.Add("Bambam Flintstone");
            SourceCollection.Add("Barny Rubble");
            SourceCollection.Add("Betty Rubble");

            ViewSource = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SourceCollection);
            ViewSource.Filter = SourceFilter;
            ViewSource.IsLiveFiltering = true;
        }

        private bool SourceFilter(object obj)
        {
            string val = (string)obj;
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Filter) || val.Contains(Filter);
        }

        public string Filter
        {
            get { return _filter; }
            set
            {
                _filter = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Filter"));
                ViewSource.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> SourceCollection { get; }
        public ListCollectionView ViewSource { get; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on that please? If I'm declaring my `CollectionViewSource` in the ViewModel where does the filtering go? Surely that would end up with a tightly coupled View and ViewModel? I also don't quite understand what to do with that answer linked... As with all the others I've looked at it lacks a comprehensive explanation of how to get from a simple bound `ObservableCollection` to the desired result.

Comment: You've already got a bound property for the filter value.  When that is changed in the VM the filter updates.  It's the same as exposing a collection except it's a viewsource.  The UI is no more tightly bound to the VM than it was before.

Comment: Ok, so if I declare in my VM something like: `public CollectionViewSource Filtered_View
        {
            get { return _filtered_View; }
            set
            {
                _filtered_View = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Filtered_View");
            }
        }` 
How should I use the Filtered_Name property in the VM? Sorry, I'm sure I'm just being a bit slow but I cannot get my head around what I need to do.