# How can we apply multiple filters on DataGridView by passing the filtered data to the second filter and so on?

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, datagrid

I have columns ("Region","Customer","Salesman","Brand","Groups","Category" and "Product") in my DataGridView now i want to first apply filter based on "Region" then on filtered data  want to apply filter on "Customer" and want to apply "Salesman" filter on filtered data. I have used this code

```
        private void BtnApplyFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
            if (RegionName != "All")
            {
                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Region='{0}'", CbRegions.Text);
            }
            if (CustomerName != "All")
            {
                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Customer='{0}'", CbCustomers.Text);
            }
            if (SalesmanName != "All")
            {

                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Salesman='{0}'", CbSalesmen.Text);
            }
            if (BrandName != "All")
            {
                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Brand='{0}'", CbBrands.Text);
            }
            if (GroupName != "All")
            {
                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Groups='{0}'", CbGroups.Text);
            }
            if (CategoryName != "All")
            {
                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Category='{0}'", CbCategories.Text);
            }
            if (ItemName != "All")
            {
                (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductName='{0}'", CbProducts.Text);
            }
            SalesView.ClearSelection();
            GetTotals();

        }
```

I have tried to combine all filter in one string using "AND" operators but that is not working because of "All" value like when user selects "All", in filter string i replace the "All" with empty string which is not working I and also tried Like operator. Now can any body please tell me how can i use / give the filtered data to the second filter and then then filtered data to third filter and so on? because when i apply second filter it does not get applied on the filtered data but on the orignal complete data.

Comment: I think your best choice is to use a collection view.  This will allow a variety of filtering as well as sorting: [Filter Data in a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and this [How to filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497506/collectionviewsource-how-to-filter-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "AND" operator should be working, but you did not show us that code, so I can't tell you why it did not in your case. Hence, try something along the lines of

```
    var criteria = new List<string>();

    if (RegionName != "All")
    {
       criteria.Add(string.Format("Region='{0}'", CbRegions.Text));
    }
    if (CustomerName != "All")
    {
        criteria.Add(string.Format("Customer='{0}'", CbCustomers.Text);
    }
    // ...
    string condition = string.Join(" AND ",criteria);
    (SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = condition;
```

And as a bonus hint: if you see code which repeats several times a line like

```
(SalesView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = /*...*/
```

do yourself a favor refactor it into a variant where this assignment takes place only once, otherwise you will produce a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score -1):

You should use “or” with “true”.

For example:
(Customer='{0}' OR true) AND (Region='{0}' OR true) ...

Comment: Looks overcomplicated to me. Any explanation why this should be necessary?

Comment: Actually, this "if" statements are unnecessary. Filtering can handle in one line: 
(Customer='{0}' OR true) AND (Region='{0}' OR true)... => this means, if data not exist in "Customer={0}" filter, "OR true" statement was added to this filter, second filter also will run.