# Filter a bounded ListView from SQL database on C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Here is my final App. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APQWr.png)

I am very new to WPF with C# and want to learn more....

Things to note:

1. Code-Behind: i have connected to SQL database running on my SQL server (locally)
2. XAML: i draw the ListView: then i "Binding"/populate each column with SQL database table
3. So far the Binding from SQL database table to ListView is working fine
4. Next, i have a TextBox drawn as well, i want to be able to use this textBox to have end-user enter keyboard and filter
   (any column) from the bounded ListView data that come from SQL database.

i tried so many Filtering option out there, most of the example are talking about filtering from locally created data Listview, not data Listview from SQL database.
NOTE: if possible, search directly from Bounded ListView or from SQL database itself, and then show the result as User is typing.

**Here is my C# Code-behind:**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillList();

        }

        public void fillList()
        {

            // SQL Database connection:
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = WideWorldImporters; User id = Test_1; Password = P @ssw0rd; Trusted_Connection = True;");

            conn.Open(); // 1st, open the SQLConnection "conn"

            string sqldata = "SELECT PersonID, FullName, PreferredName FROM Application.People"; //define string to query SQLcommand "SELEC" and From database
            SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = sqldata;

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Application.People");
            sda.Fill(dt);

            lvData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; //this bind point to the listview in XAML file: Name="lvUsers"
            conn.Close();

            // sorting by PersonID column:

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvData.ItemsSource);
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PersonID", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        }

  

        private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

**And here is my XAML code:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="500">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500">


        <ListView Name="lvData" Margin="0,145,0,69" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="370" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Person ID" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Full Name"  Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Preferred Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PreferredName}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextChanged="txt_search_TextChanged"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you run the app, you got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc7gl.png)

Comment: So where is the code where you try to apply the filtering?

Comment: @burnsi, i don't know is there a better way to accomplish the codes? better than current one and yet achieve 2 things that i want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CollectionViewSource, how to filter data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497506/collectionviewsource-how-to-filter-data)

Comment: @burnsi, i have read post regarding this CollectionViewSource, iCollectionView and i counldn't put this into practice as for my project....